# How to convert *elbv2.DescribeLoadBalancersOutput to an JSON in goLang to perform data parsing

Tags: json, go, aws-sdk-go

I have been trying to work with AWS Go SDK Version 2. I am getting an where I want to convert the response I got from **DescribeLoadBalancer()** function into a JSON, so that I can parse it and perform further action but when I try to follow how to parse the JSON in go describe here https://blog.alexellis.io/golang-json-api-client/. I get an error in the compiler that I can't convert ***elbv2.DescribeLoadBalancersOutput** into **[]byte**. I tried different approaches i.e trying to convert ***elbv2.DescribeLoadBalancersOutput** into **string** etc but I always get the same error i.e cannot convert  ***elbv2.DescribeLoadBalancersOutput** into the specified type. hence want to understand what would be the best to perform the required action. Here's my code.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/elbv2"
)

type LoadBalancerARN struct {
    loadBalancerARN string
}

func main() {
    session, error := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("eu-central-1"),
    })
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot create a session, %v", error)
    }

    service := elbv2.New(session)

    input := &elbv2.DescribeLoadBalancersInput{}

    getLoadBalancersJson, error := service.DescribeLoadBalancers(input)
    if error != nil {
        if aerr, ok := error.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            case elbv2.ErrCodeLoadBalancerNotFoundException:
                fmt.Println(elbv2.ErrCodeLoadBalancerNotFoundException, aerr.Error())
            default:
                fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Println(error.Error())
        }
        return
    }

    encodinglbJson := gob.NewEncoder(getLoadBalancersJson)

    //var arn LoadBalancerARN

    fmt.Println(getLoadBalancersJson)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(getLoadBalancersJson))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I have figured the above out, best way to do the above is, AWS provide a LoadBalancer function which convert the ***elbv2.DescribeLoadBalancersOutput** into an object of type **[]*elbv2.LoadBalancer** and then you can convert that object into the byte array using **json.Marshal** function and from there you can perform the parsing as needed.

Here's code

```
type LoadBalancerJSONStructure struct {
    LoadBalancerArn       string
    DNSName               string
    CanonicalHostedZoneId string
    CreatedTime           string
    LoadBalancerName      string
    Scheme                string
    VpcId                 string
    Type                  string
    IpAddressType         string
}
```

```
response, error := json.Marshal(getLoadBalancers.LoadBalancers)
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error, %v", error)
    }

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(getLoadBalancers.LoadBalancers))

    var lbJson LoadBalancerJSONStructure

    err := json.Unmarshal(response, &lbJson)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Struct is: ", lbJson)
```